# select tags with database in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have an issue that i need to learn how to solve! I'm making a submission form which consists of some select tags drop menus! so all of these drop menus are getting the data from the database i did that but the issue is that i need when i select something from Drop menu#1 i make a query and choose the matching data from the database and post them to Drop menu#2 ! so here is my code :-

```
<?php
echo "Choose your Source :<select name='source' value='Source'>
                      <option> </otpion>";
$sql = "SELECT City_name FROM city";
$info = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($info)) {
    echo "<option > '" . @$row[0] . "'</option>";
}

echo "</select>";
echo "Choose your Destination :<select name='destination' value='Destination'>
                            <option> </otpion>";
echo @$source = $_POST['source'];
$sql = "SELECT Destination FROM Schedule  WHERE Source ='" . @$source . "'";
$info = mysql_query($sql);

while (@$row = mysql_fetch_array($info)) {
    echo "<option selected='selected'>'" . @$row['0'] . "'</option>";
}

echo "</select><br />";
?>
```

so now all i want to know, how can i get values from the database into "destination" drop menu when i select a value from "source" drop menu without refreshing the page nor clicking any buttons! thanks in advance .

Comment: Honestly, from what source in the wild internet did you learn to write such code or where did you copy it from?? It's absolutely terrible! A mixture of PHP, HTML, SQL (bad), full of error supressors (bad), uses the mysql_* API (bad, deprecated), is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (dangerous).

Comment: Forget everything you've learned about PHP and start again, here: http://www.phptherightway.com/

Comment: @markus-tharkun what is this assault man? i am still learning!!!

Comment: It's not an assault on you, it's outrage about the fact that there STILL exists such horrible stuff out there...

Comment: @markus-tharkun - It's comments like yours that detract many people from learning more about programming and that is sad. There is a way to provide feedback and constructive criticism and yours was not that way. More experienced programmers like yourself should encourage others who are new or struggling in order to foster a more positive and ultimately more collaborative environment.

Comment: @Nicarus I'm really thankful for you man, thanks a lot really!

Comment: Maybe, the sad truth is, if you don't scream it from time to time, when it just gets too much ;) it will never change.

Comment: @markus-tharkun - I completely understand where you are coming from on this, but I disagree with the response. I think you need to choose these battles a little better. The guy was just asking for a little help.

Comment: @Nicarus I agree with you from that perspective. I just think people need to know, when it's too bad, pampering doesn't serve anyone. PHP's repuation is partially also bad because we tolerated bad code being reused and reposted on the internet for too long.

Comment: I agree that I wouldn't serve it like that face-to-face and it's not good feedback practice... I still see my comment as a general cry of outrage, not as an assault on a specific person. I'm sure he's not to blame, the community is.

Comment: @markus-tharkun - Amen to that. It's hard to separate sometimes. Also, thanks for sharing that link - I've been digging around it myself. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will require client-side scripting, like JavaScript. It appears you may be wanting to use AJAX, which would leverage JavaScript and allow you to make a call to your PHP file(s) on the server (and ultimately you database) without causing the page to refresh.

If you aren't familiar with AJAX, I suggest you do some research. You're best bet would be to use a JavaScript library with AJAX functions already available - like jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/